# JSON extract sub key+value array

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

In Oracle Pl/sql from the below json format for type="complaint" how can I get "partialSuccessWarning" element full text data value for further processing?

I am new to json pl/sql and any help is appreciated

JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "type": "customer",
    "existingCount": 2,
    "createdCount": 0,
    "partialSuccessCount": 0,
    "erroredCount": 0,
    "totalCount": 8,
    "createdRecords": [
      
    ],
    "existingRecords": [
      "791304",
      "2154046"
    ],
    "error": {
      
    },
    "partialSuccessWarning": {
      
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "complaint",
    "existingCount": 3,
    "createdCount": 2,
    "partialSuccessCount": 3,
    "erroredCount": 0,
    "totalCount": 8,
    "createdRecords": [
      "VS-548982"
    ],
    "existingRecords": [
      "VS-548988",
      "VS-548986",
      "VS-548984"
    ],
    "error": {
      
    },
    "partialSuccessWarning": {
      "VS-548986": [
        "[TLM-TEST-SERIAL] does not exist or could not be loaded."
      ],
      "VS-548984": [
        "[TLM-TEST-SERIAL] does not exist or could not be loaded."
      ],
      "VS-548982": [
        "[TLM-TEST-SERIAL] does not exist or could not be loaded."
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use SQL with [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) function which is available starting with Oracle DB `12.1.0.2` version, but as you need to get the value and use further, then assign the returning values to some variables through creating a stored function of return type `SYS_REFCURSOR` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Warnings RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  JsonArray   VARCHAR2(32767);
  arrWarnings VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  JsonArray :='[
                {
                  "type": "customer",
                  "existingCount": 2,
                   ...
                }
              ]';
  arrWarnings := JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arrWarnings);

  v_sql :=
      'SELECT "VS-548986","VS-548984","VS-548982"
         FROM dual
        CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(:Warnings,
                                     ''$'' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH ''$[*]."partialSuccessWarning"''
                                                  COLUMNS(
                                                          "VS-548986"  VARCHAR2(1000) PATH ''$."VS-548986"[*]'',
                                                          "VS-548984"  VARCHAR2(1000) PATH ''$."VS-548982"[*]'',
                                                          "VS-548982"  VARCHAR2(1000) PATH ''$."VS-548982"[*]''
                                                          )
                                                )
                        )';
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql USING arrWarnings;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from *SQL Developer*'s console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
      result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_Warnings;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result ;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a0cf433e17a464f0c24dd872094e66b)</kbd>

**Edit :** There are restricted number of functions, which are `JSON_TABLE`, `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY`, for `JSON` within `Oracle12c`, while we need to determine the **Keys** for the `JSON` expression. Then we can alternatively use Regular Expression functions to extract the key values in order to construct the SQL statement(`v_sql`) along with `JSON_TABLE()` dynamically in such a way of creating the following function, considering simplified form of your original `JSON` format as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Warnings RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
      v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
      JsonArray   VARCHAR2(32767);
      arrWarnings VARCHAR2(1000);
      v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
      v_keys      VARCHAR2(32767);
      v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
      JsonArray :='[
                    {
                      "partialSuccessWarning": {
                        "VS-548986": [
                          "aaa"
                        ],
                        "VS-548984": [
                          "bbb"
                        ],
                        "VS-548982": [
                          "ccc"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]';
      arrWarnings := JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$');

        WITH t(JA) AS
        (
         SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$[*]."partialSuccessWarning"')
           FROM dual
        ), t2 AS
        (                
           SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( JA , '[^[]+',1,level ), '(.*")(\S+)(":.*)', '\2') AS keys, level AS lvl
             FROM t
          CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT( JA, '\["' )
        )
        SELECT LISTAGG( '"'||keys||'"',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl),
               LISTAGG( '"'||keys||'" VARCHAR2(1000) PATH ''$."'||keys||'"[*]''',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl)
          INTO v_keys, v_cols     
          FROM t2; 

      v_sql :=
      'SELECT '||v_keys||
      '  FROM dual
        CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(:Warnings,
                              ''$'' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH ''$[*]."partialSuccessWarning"''
                                            COLUMNS('||v_cols||')
                                            )
                   )';
      OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql USING arrWarnings;
      RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

which would yield the result

| VS-548986 | VS-548984 | VS-548982 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc |

Comment: Thanks for the response..Let me make it clear with simple example.
Below is sample of myJSON

1) In my case column names "open","close" are dynamic but there will always be TWO ...so not sure how read by POSITIONAL notation not knowing columns

2) as a workaround I thought I will loop through "data" keys,value... But How to get "data" full text?

Comment: VS-548986,VS-548984 are dynamic in my case. ACtually the target is to print those under "partialSuccessWarning"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: well, I've added the dynamic case @RaviKiran